# How to use ProjectTo with Automapper 8.0 Dependency injection

Tags: entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm using Automapper's (8.0) DI pattern in my project and am looking to start using ProjectTo in my Entity Framework Core entity queries.

Here is an example of what I have managed to get to work:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>> GetStuffAsync() {

    return await _dbContext.SomeEntity
        .ProjectTo<SomeViewModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

The above call returns all the expected records but it requires both injecting `IMapper` in the constructor of the repository as well as a Using reference to AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.

There are two versions of the AutoMapper docs that I have found and they seem to provide conflicting info.

These docs https://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html state the following:

> Using DI is effectively mutually exclusive with using the
> `IQueryable.ProjectTo` extension method. Use
> `IEnumerable.Select(_mapper.Map<DestinationType>).ToList()` instead.

And these docs http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dependency-injection.html state this:

> Starting with 8.0 you can use `IMapper.ProjectTo`. For older versions
> you need to pass the configuration to the extension method
> `IQueryable.ProjectTo<T>(IConfigurationProvider)`.

Following the first documentation's example, I converted my query to this:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> GetStuff() {

    return _dbContext.SomeEntity
        .Select(_mapper.Map<SomeViewModel>)
        .ToList();
}
```

However, that method returns 0 records (the previous returned everything) and the method needed to be converted from Async to synchronous as ToListAsync() wasn't supported by the extended Select. Clearly I'm missing something. Also, I'm not sure if that is the correct technique as the second set of docs talk about using IMapper.ProjectTo for version 8.0 without passing the configuration to the extension method. How do I do that?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> Starting with 8.0 you can use IMapper.ProjectTo

This means that now `IMapper` interface has a method `ProjectTo` (similar to `Map`). So while you still need injecting `IMapper` (but you need it anyway if you were using `Map`, so no difference), you don't need `QueryableExtensions` and `ProjectTo` *extension* method - you simply use the interface method (similar to `Map`):

```cs
return await _mapper.ProjectTo<SomeViewModel>(dbContext.SomeEntity)
    .ToListAsync();
```

---

Please note that there is fundamental difference between `_mapper.ProjectTo` and `Select(_mapper.Map)` - the former is translated to SQL and executed server side, while the latter leads to [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation) and needs `Include` / `ThenInclude` (or lazy loading) in order to function properly.

Comment: That did the trick. Is there a reference or example in the docs for this function that I missed?

Comment: Nope. As you know, there is no AutoMapper API reference. So the `IMapper.ProjectTo` is only mentioned in the second link from your post. And of course the VS Intellisense :)

Comment: If I understand Ivan's answer correctly, which of the two is the best answer here, _mapper.ProjectTo or Select(_mapper.Map)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and this worked for me:

```
var teacher = _mapper.ProjectTo<TeacherReadDto>(_applicationDb.Teachers.Where(x=>x.Id==id));
```